# How to set different throttle scopes for different users using django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For eg: for customers and employee's set different throttle rates.
Can this be done using `UserRateThrottle`? eg:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES'] = ('backend.throttles.EmployeeThrottle')
REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES'] = {
    'user': config.THROTTLE_RATE,
    'employee': config.EMPLOYEE_THROTTLE_RATE
}

from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class EmployeeThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    *WHAT TO DO HERE?*
```

Can I get request somehow in this `EmployeeThrottle` class and set scope based on that request content.

EDIT: eg: [UserRateThrottle](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#userratethrottle) here in `BurstRateThrottle`, if somehow I can get request I can set scope based on that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is per user type, then you should use `BaseThrottle` as base class. I think smth like this should work?

```
class UserRateThrottle(throttling.BaseThrottle):
    scope = 'user'
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        return request.user.type == 'user'


class EmployeeRateThrottle(throttling.BaseThrottle):
    scope = 'employee'
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        return request.user.type == 'employee'
```

Comment: how will DRF know which scope to set( which function to call). UserRateThrottle or EmployeeRateThrottle?

Comment: It will pick it up by the scope name attr defined in view and `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES` setting

Comment: I don't want it to define view by view. I want all API's to either have `user` throttle or `employee` throttle rates depending on the request.user type. I want to check beforehand if user is customer or employee.

Comment: What do you mean? You only have to define these two classes and add them to `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES` setting

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle


class CustomThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        employee_scope = getattr(view, 'employee', None)
        user_scope = getattr(view, 'user', None)
        if request.user.profile.is_employee:
            if not employee_scope:
                return True
            self.scope = employee_scope
        else:
            if not user_scope:
                return True
            self.scope = user_scope 
            
        self.rate = self.get_rate()
        self.num_requests, self.duration = self.parse_rate(self.rate)
        
        return super().allow_request(request, view)
```